# Magento2: Get category by name?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category

I want to retrieve the products under a certain category. Now what I'm trying to do is pass the Category Name and retrieve the actual Category ID. So in return I can use this category id to retrieve the products under this category. My previous code didn't work anymore although it worked previously but now it's not working anymore

Below is my current code

```
public function getProductsCategoryByName() 
{
    $categoryName = "Extra category";
    $categoryCollection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryName)->setPageSize(1);

    if ($categoryCollection->getSize()) {

        $categoryId = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getId();


        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

        $product_collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) 
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

        return $product_collection;
    }

    return null;        
}
```

Comment: can you check if you are getting category id from your code? If you are getting category id, then problem would be in you product collection code

Comment: the IF condition for $categoryCollection->getSize() returns 0 so basically it's not getting the category by the name

Comment: Print  Collection query `$categoryCollection->getSelect()->__toString()`  and  run this query to database and check what  result comming. I think, you have different for  name for store view level

Comment: @AmitBera the $categoryCollection is empty that's why I can't check it

Comment: let check my post

Answer (score 0):

try this code here you pass category name this function return product collection

```
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $collecionFactory;
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->collecionFactory = $collecionFactory;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        $data = $this->collecionFactory->create();
        $data->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryName)
        //print_r($data->getData());
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
            ->load(4);
        //echo $category->getName();
        $category_name = 'Bags'; \\ your category name
        $prd_coll = $this->getProductsCategoryByName($category_name);
        print_r($prd_coll->getData());
        exit();
    }
    public function getProductsCategoryByName($category_name)
    {
        $collection = '';
        $category_collaction = $this->collecionFactory->create();
        foreach ($category_collaction as $key => $value) {
            //print_r($value->getId());
            $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($value->getId());
            if ($category->getName() == $category_name) {

                $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($value->getId());

                $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                break;
            }
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work also.. It returned an empty string

Comment: @MadzQuestioning  it return empty because category name not have any product

Comment: please put right category name

Comment: I already did and double check the category. It has 4 products and all products are visible and enabled and has stock assigned to it

Comment: please check your category name  because code is running perfectly . i put screenshot

Answer (score 0):

But do not use object manager directly.

```
          $name = 'women';

          $bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
          $objectManager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $_categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

            $collection = $_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$name);
            if ($collection->getSize()) {
              print_r($collection->getFirstItem()->getId().'<br/>');


            }
```